# How can I add the beginning of a URL to variable?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I wrote a short PHP script to scrape the images from the homepage of http://www.imgur.com. Here is the code:

```
$imgur = file_get_html('http://www.imgur.com');
foreach($imgur->find('div[class="post"]') as $images)
    echo "<span id=\"images\">$images</span>";
```

The problem is that after scraping the divs with class=post, the pictures link to the gallery for the image, but the "a href=" looks like /gallery/48ZPT instead of http://www.imgur.com/gallery/48ZPT.

So when I click the link where the images are on my website it takes me to mysite.com/gallery/48ZPT but that directory doesn't exist so I get an error.

Is there anyway to add "http://www.imgur.com" to each variable href as it is pulled from the site?

I know this might be a little confusing, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Which class you are using for parsing DOM ? Simple DOM Parser ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have stated that. This is the URL of the parser I'm using - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
$imgur = file_get_html('http://www.imgur.com');
foreach($imgur->find('div[class="post"]') as $images)
{
    echo "<span id=\"images\">"."http://www.imgur.com"."$images</span>";
}
```

Comment: This also just adds the URL directly above the image instead of changing the URL of the image.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean ? @emagdnim